# How to solve mp3 file path for swf audio player in localhost/website?

Tags: html, flash, audio, localhost

i made a **index.html** file which have this script.

```
<html>
<body>

<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player-mini.swf?mp3=file:\\\D:\music\aa.mp3" width="160" height="20" id="dewplayer-mini"><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="movie" value="player-mini.swf?mp3=file:\\\D:\music\aa.mp3" /></object>

</body>
</html>
```

I used **Dew Player** as audio player for my website, the problem is, when i open this index.html file using localhost, then mp3 not play, while when i open this index.html file directly [by double click] , then mp3 play fine.

I know problem is Mp3 file path, plz tell how i give the mp3 file path so it will work fine in localhost. [Dew player is not problem].

Answer (score 0):

You are using `file:\\\` protocol

Change your remove `file:\\\` from your path to file (Move your `aa.mp3` to where your `index.html` exists

```
<html>
<body>

<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player-mini.swf?mp3={Path_TO_Mp3}/aa.mp3" width="160" height="20" id="dewplayer-mini"><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="movie" value="player-mini.swf?mp3={Path_TO_Mp3}/aa.mp3" /></object>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have 270GB Audio file, what you want from me that i move all my files in localhost, i know what you want to say, but i need a solution so i can access the my audio files outside of localhost folder..

Comment: Actually yeah, if you want to play those with files over `HTTP` you have to move them to WAMP `www` directory.